# How to check available Python libraries on Google App Engine & add more

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sqlite

How to check available Python libraries on Google App Engine & add more?

Is SQLite available or we must use GQL with their database system only?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite is there (but since you cannot write to files, you must use it in a read-only way, or on a `:memory:` database).

App engine [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Pure_Python) do a good job at documenting what's there. You can add any other pure-python library, typically as a zipfile of `.py` (NOT `.pyc`) files to upload in the main directory of your app (you can directly import from inside the zipfile, of course).

A few more pure-Python third-party libraries included with app engine are listed and documented [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html) -- the paragraph on zipimport at this URL has a bit more details on the ways and limitations of using zipfiles to add more third-party pure-Python libs to your app.

Comment: Thank you Alex for detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, you can only use the GAE specific database.